# Bluetooth 5 Android scan Phy Coded widow / interval - latency

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-5

I am testing Android bluetooth scan phy coded (ScanSettings-PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED)

But I see that the Android phone (MI9) scans only 1 second with an interval of 10 seconds for Phy Coded.

How I can change the window/interval to reduce the latency for Phy Coded?
Is there any documentation about these timings?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please, does anyone have an idea?